# GNU Radio on CentOS missing QT Blocks

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I was trying to follow through with GNU Radio [Tutorial 2](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_GRC), but I wasn't able to find any of the QT blocks in the library. The tutorial wants me to use QT GUI Time Sink, but it and many similar blocks are missing from my library.

[What the tutorial says my search should return.](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/images/thumb/9/95/Search.png/200px-Search.png)
[My search, following the tutorial.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKtmi.png)

[Searching for the specific block.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/928AL.png)

The version yum installed for me is 3.7.11. I received no errors during installation.

I even tried porting in the tutorial's finished code, but the block was marked as a Missing Block.

[Tutorial 2's GUI Representation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8nnS.png)

How do I incorporate these blocks in the library?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CentOS, but based on your description, the GNU Radio package you installed was compiled without QT support. You will have to find a different package or compile GNU Radio yourself.

Also note that GNU Radio 3.7.11 is a very old version, from 2017. Therefore another reason to install a better package, with a current version, is to get new blocks and bug fixes from the past three years.